# Updating the prefix for a guild doesent require a full restart to apply but adding a new guild to my database does for some reason

Tags: javascript, mysql, discord.js

so i have code setup so when a guild joins they are added to the database with default settings i setup. if they decide to change the prefix it works fine they  can change the prefix and it will update and they can immediately start using it.

BUT for some reason when a guild is added i have to restart the bot or use nodemon and make it auto restart upon changes for that new guild before they can use ANY commands. is there a difference in how im adding this info to the database compared to adding the prefix?

below is the code i use to add the server to the database and below that is the code i use to let them change prefix. im trying to get the commands to work for the server that just invited the bot without having to restart the bot to avoid bugs down the line when its trying to do something and is then restarted cause someone invited the bot.

```js
/// adding a guild to the database upon invite
bot.on('guildCreate', async (guild) => {
    // Guild the user needs to have the role in
    let myGuild = await bot.guilds.fetch(process.env.BOT_GUILD);
    console.log(myGuild);

    // Role that the user needs
    let requiredRole = process.env.PAID_ROLE;
    console.log(requiredRole);

    // find default channel
    let defaultChannel = "";
    guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel) => {
      if(channel.type == "text" && defaultChannel == "") {
        if(channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES")) {
          defaultChannel = channel;
          console.log(defaultChannel);
        }
      }
    });

    // Member object of the user in guildA
    try{
        let guildOwner = await myGuild.members.fetch(guild.ownerID);
        console.log(guildOwner);

        if (!guildOwner)
        return console.log(`Oops, ${guild.owner} is not a member of your server.`);
    }catch(error) {
        return console.log(`Oops, ${guild.owner} is not a member of your server.`),
        defaultChannel.send('Please kick the bot, have the guild owner join this discord https://discord.gg/tDTjBAaCAn, Then you can reinvite the bot and you will be properly added to the database and can use the bot! dont forget to check out the premium features while your there if you decide you want more features from Gate Bot!');
    }
    //Check if they have the role 
    let guildOwner = await myGuild.members.fetch(guild.ownerID);
    let ownerHasPaidRole = guildOwner.roles.cache.has(process.env.PAID_ROLE);

    if (ownerHasPaidRole){
      console.log(`Woohoo, ${guildOwner} has the required role`);}
        try {
            /// insert serverid and serverownerid into servers db
        await connection.query(
            `INSERT INTO Servers (serverId, serverOwnerId, paidRole) VALUES ('${guild.id}', '${guild.ownerID}', 1)`
            );
            /// insert server id into serverconfig db
        await connection.query(
            `INSERT INTO ServerConfig (serverId) VALUES ('${guild.id}')`
            );
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
    }});
```

---

Message handler to use the change prefix command

```js
///allowing the script to see files from the commands folder
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
   const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
   bot.commands.set(command.name, command);
}



///Message Handler
    bot.on('message', async (message) => {
        const prefix = guildCommandPrefixes.get(message.guild.id);
        console.log('caught message');
        if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
        const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

   ///basic ping pong test command
    if(command === 'help'){
        bot.commands.get('help').execute(message);
    }
    ///basic ping pong test command
    else if(command === 'ping'){
        bot.commands.get('ping').execute(message);
    }
    ///change the servers prefix
    else if(command === 'changeprefix'){
        bot.commands.get('changeprefix').execute(message, connection, prefix, guildCommandPrefixes);
    }   
    ///arguments test
    else if (command === 'argsinfo'){
        bot.commands.get('argsinfo').execute(message, command, args)
    }
    ///message command list
    else if (command === 'autoungate'){
        bot.commands.get('autoungate').execute(message, args, Discord);
    }});
```

command used to change prefix.

```js
module.exports= {
    name: 'changeprefix',
    description: "this will change the prefix in the database for the set guild id",
    execute: async (message, connection, prefix, guildCommandPrefixes) =>{
        setTimeout(() => {message.delete();}, 3000);
        if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + 'changeprefix')){
            if (message.member.id === message.guild.ownerID) {
                var guild = message.guild
                paidRole = await connection.query(`SELECT paidRole FROM Servers Where '${guild}' === serverId`);
                const [cmdName, newPrefix ] = message.content.split(" ");
                if (paidRole === '1'){
                if (newPrefix) {
                    try {
                        await connection.query(
                        `UPDATE ServerConfig SET cmdPrefix = '${newPrefix}' WHERE serverId= '${message.guild.id}'`
                    );
                    guildCommandPrefixes.set(message.guild.id, newPrefix);
                    message.channel.send(`Updated guild prefix to ${newPrefix}`).then(sentMessage => {sentMessage.delete({ timeout: 3000}); });
                }catch(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    message.channel.send(`Failed to update guild prefix to ${newPrefix}`).then(sentMessage => {sentMessage.delete({ timeout: 3000}); });
                }}
                else {
                    message.channel.send('You need to input a prefix to change to!').then(sentMessage => {sentMessage.delete({ timeout: 3000}); });
                 }}
                else {
                    message.channel.send('You need to purchase the premium version for prefix customization.').then(sentMessage => {sentMessage.delete({ timeout: 3000}); });
                }}
                else {
                    message.channel.send('You do not have permissions to do this command!').then(sentMessage => {sentMessage.delete({ timeout: 3000}); });
            }
        }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made sure my `paidRole` variable in my database could be set to `null`.

Upon guild creation the guild is marked `null` for a split second to get it in the database. I used `UPDATE` to update the role to either `1` or `0` in the database based on their role in my Discord.

When you use `UPDATE` it will "refresh" the bot and apply automatically some changes *without* making it restart possibly causing some issues.

Here's the code I ended up using:

```js
/// adding a guild to the database upon invite
bot.on('guildCreate', async (guild) => {
    // Guild the user needs to have the role in
    let myGuild = await bot.guilds.fetch(process.env.BOT_GUILD);

    try {
        /// insert serverid and serverownerid into servers db
    await connection.query(
        `INSERT INTO Servers (serverId, serverOwnerId, paidRole) VALUES ('${guild.id}', '${guild.ownerID}', NULL)`
        );
        /// insert server id into serverconfig db
    await connection.query(
        `INSERT INTO ServerConfig (serverId) VALUES ('${guild.id}')`
        );
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);

    // find default channel
    let defaultChannel = "";
    guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel) => {
      if(channel.type == "text" && defaultChannel == "") {
        if(channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES")) {
          defaultChannel = channel;
          console.log(defaultChannel);
        }
      }
    });

    // Member object of the user in guildA
    try{
        let guildOwner = await myGuild.members.fetch(guild.ownerID);

        if (!guildOwner)
        return console.log(`Oops, ${guild.owner} is not a member of your server.`);
    }catch(error) {
        return console.log(`Oops, ${guild.owner} is not a member of your server.`),
        defaultChannel.send('Please kick the bot, have the guild owner join this discord https://discord.gg/tDTjBAaCAn, Then you can reinvite the bot and you will be properly added to the database and can use the bot! dont forget to check out the premium features while your there if you decide you want more features from Gate Bot!');
    }
    //Check if they have the role 
    let guildOwner = await myGuild.members.fetch(guild.ownerID);
    let ownerHasPaidRole = guildOwner.roles.cache.has(process.env.PAID_ROLE);

    if (ownerHasPaidRole){
      console.log(`Woohoo, ${guildOwner} has the required role`);
      await connection.query(
          `UPDATE Servers SET paidRole = '1' WHERE serverId = ${guild.id}`
      );
    }
    else {
        await connection.query(
           `UPDATE Servers SET paidRole = '0' WHERE serverId = ${guild.id}`
        );
    }
    }});
```